# Add Value on Button Click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add the corresponding values when each button is clicked?

With my current script it almost works but it adds each of the previous values instead of just adding the current value:

```
jQuery(function() {
    total = 0;
    jQuery("input").click(function() {
        jQuery("input:checked").not('input[value="reset"]').each(function() {
            total += parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
        });
        jQuery("#Totalcost").html("Save up to " + total + "%");
    });

    jQuery('input[value="reset"]').click(function(){
        jQuery('span#Totalcost').html("Calculate your Savings!");
        total = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: please show us the HTML also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare global visible variable.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75rzb82p/)

```
var total = 0;

jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("input").click(function() {
        jQuery("input:checked").not('input[value="reset"]').each(function() {
            total += parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
        });
        jQuery("#Totalcost").html("Save up to " + total + "%");
    });

    jQuery('input[value="reset"]').click(function(){
        jQuery('span#Totalcost').html("Calculate your Savings!");
        jQuery("input:checked").prop('checked', false);
        total = 0;
    });
});
```

**Information**

`total` variable is declared outsite `jQuery(function (){` because I dont know do You not need this variable outside this function.

Btw. Maybe You are interested [jQuery change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)?

I think this is better choice in this case.

Comment: Edited. Unchecking all checked inputs, was added.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set your `total` back to zero each time a checkbox is clicked. Reset your `total` back to zero within your click event handler:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var total = 0;
    jQuery("input").click(function() {
        total = 0;
        jQuery("input:checked").not('input[value="reset"]').each(function() {
            total += parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
        });
        jQuery("#Totalcost").html("Save up to " + total + "%");
    });

    jQuery('input[value="reset"]').click(function(){
        jQuery('span#Totalcost').html("Calculate your Savings!");
        total = 0;
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/973vbLL3/1/)

Comment: This almost works, except for the Reset button. How can I make it work? When a user presses Reset, it should uncheck all the inputs and set the total to 0.